# Cached Version of $(this) Not Working

Tags: jquery, caching, this

I've been trying to cache $(this) in a variable named $this for my JQuery code to improve efficiency but when I try to refer to $this within a click handler function it doesn't work; however, using $(this) does. Here's my code without the cached version of $(this).

```
$(function() {
    var listNav = $('.row .listNav'),
        listItem = listNav.find('li'),
                    $this = $(this);

        listItem.click(function() {

            listItem.removeClass('selected');
            $this.addClass('selected');
        });
});
```

If I try to create the variable within the list of variables at the top and then reference it within the four click functions it doesn't work.

Comment: Please reduce it to a reasonable minimum. It's really no reason for us to read hundred lines of code.

Comment: I believe it will work if you remove the $ from the variable name and just say 'var this = $(this);'

Comment: @DavidScott: No, there is nothing wrong with using `$this`, i do it all the time.

Comment: On top of the reduction zerkms is looking for it would be more appropriate to see what you were doing that didnt work...

Comment: How are we supposed to tell you the problem if you post the version with the relevant code removed?

Comment: Still too much. How the line `slideWidth = $('.slide').width()` is useful for the problem description?

Comment: Where is the cached version of `$(this)`? How is it used?

Comment: I updated it so that it's essentially just removing the class "selected" from any items in the list that currently have the class and then adding the class to the item that was clicked. However, since the cached version isn't working, nothing happens. Sorry for posting too much code initially thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(this) creates a jQuery object from the context at the time it is called. `this` changes according to which click handler has been fired, so caching it at the top of the code won't give you the result you want.

If you need to access `$(this)` more than once or twice in a handler, cache it in the handler.

```
$this = $(this);  // won't work because 'this' is different in the handler.

    bullet.click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);    // Will work as it's defined in the right context
        var bulletStr = $this.text(),
            bulletNum = parseInt(bulletStr),
            bulletMargin = slideWidth * bulletNum;

        bullet.removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');
        current = bulletNum;
        if(current >= lastSlide) {
            nextBtn.hide();
        }
        else if(current < lastSlide) {
            nextBtn.show();
        }
        if(current > 0) {
            prevBtn.show();
        }
        else {
            prevBtn.hide();
        }
        sliderInner.animate({marginLeft: -bulletMargin}, 300, "easeInOutQuad");
        listItem.removeClass('selected');
        listItem.eq(bulletNum).addClass('selected');
    });
```

Comment: No, the function will have access to the scope in which it is defined. so the `$this` defined outside the handler should work as well.

Comment: no, `var $this = $(this)` makes absolutely no sense outside the handler functions.

Comment: It depend on if he want the `this` from within the handler, or the `this` from the parent scope. Technically the `$this` from outside is avaailable from within the handler... if jsut may not be the element he wants.

Comment: why would he want `$(this)` outside the handlers? That's same as `$(document)` i.e. makes absolutely no sense unless you are going for obfuscation.

Comment: The OP is trying to improve performance by caching $(this), but he's just hit on the wrong place to do it. The principle is good, but I question the value of caching in these handlers, since he's not using $(this) very much anyway.

Comment: Depends on where you are definng things. For example if for some godforsaken reason you are attaching new handlers in a callback you may need access to the "parent" version of `$(this)`. Im not saying this answer is incorrect, im saying that technically `$this` defined outside is still avialable in the handler.

Comment: @prodigitalson Technically you are correct, but irrelevant. The OP asks why his handlers don't work. They don't work because  assigning `$this` outside the handler gives the wrong value for `$this` when the handler is called.

Answer (score 0):

How do you init it?
if you do something like

$this = $(this);

It MUST not work, becouse in the list `this` contains scope of you function, but not eventual `clicks` scope

you do something like

```
var that; // - without initing it
```

and then do

```
but.click = function(){
    that = $(this);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using

```
listItem.click(function(data)
```

instead of

```
listItem.click(function()
```